# Bash script - wait for all xargs processes to be finished

Tags: linux, bash, process, web-crawler, xargs

I have written a small bash script for crawling an XML sitemap of URLs. It retrieves 5 URLs in parallel using xargs.

Now I want an E-Mail to be sent when all URLs have been crawled, so it has to wait until all sub-processes of xargs have finished and then send the mail.

I have tried with a pipe after the xargs:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget --quiet --no-cache -O- http://some.url/test.xml | egrep -o "http://some.url[^<]+" | xargs -P 5 -r -n 1 wget --spider | mail...
```

and with `wait`

```
#!/bin/bash

wget --quiet --no-cache -O- http://some.url/test.xml | egrep -o "http://some.url[^<]+" | xargs -P 5 -r -n 1 wget --spider

wait

mail ...
```

Which both doesn't work, the email is sent immediately after the script is executed. 
How can I achieve this? Unfortunately I don't have the `parallel` program on my server (managed hosting).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100) in Stack Overflow. You'll collect PID(s) of your curl(s) with `$!` and then wait them (each of them as if some of them have already finished, waits will return immediately).

Comment: How would I do that? Since xargs starts the child-processes, I don't have the possibility to get the PIDs? And xargs starts new processes automatically as soon as one finishes.

Comment: Good point. I'd avoid the xargs and instead do some loops. That got too long to add to a comment; hence, an answer below.

Comment: I found out that my second version with the `wait` is actually working now, no idea why it wasn't working at the time I tested it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `xargs`, spawn each `wget` individually on the background and collect the PIDs of background processes in a list. Additionally, ensure that the output of background processes gets written to a file.

Once all background processes have been spawned, go through *all* PIDs on the list and `wait` each one -- the ones already exited will not block at `wait`. Having now, hopefully, waited all background processes successfully, all there is left to do is to concatenate outputs from each background process to a single file and mail that to wherever output is needed.

Something along the lines of (echos are, of course, redundant and for demonstration purposes only):

```
#!/bin/bash

mail=$(tempfile)
pids=()
outputs=()

trap "rm -f ${outputs[@]}" EXIT
trap "rm -f $mail" EXIT

for url in $(wget --quiet --no-cache -O- http://some.url/test.xml |\
             egrep -o "http://some.url[^<]+") ; do
  output=$(tempfile)
  wget --spider > $output 2>&1 &
  pids+=($!)
  outputs+=($output)
  echo "Spawned wget and got PID ${pids[-1]}."
done

for pid in ${pids[@]} ; do
  echo "Waiting for PID $pid."
  wait $pid
done

# Concatenate outputs from individual processes into a single file.
for output in ${outputs[@]} ; do cat $output >> $mail ; done

# Mail that file.
< $mail mail -s "All outputs" some.user@some.domain

# end of file.
```

Comment: Hi Sami, thanks for your example. While that would work possibly, spawning all wget processes simultaneously is not an option here, because I have about 10000 URLs in that XML sitemap. So that would mean 10000 simultaneous wget procesesses, which is likely to be too much for the server.

Comment: Obviously you could fiddle with the for-loop a bit to make it spawn a dozen, then wait those etc. I'm sure you know how Server Fault is not a free programming service, so you're kind of expected to improve on the examples given in answers.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thanks. I found out that my second version with the `wait` is actually working now, no idea why it wasn't working at the time I tested it for the first time.